# In Pycharm, Python 2.7 is not accepting Chinese at all

Tags: python-2.7

I am working in Python 2.7, and trying Chinese in string but it is not accepting at all.

I tried .encode('utf-8') as explained in ,

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

and adding below line in the beginning of file but none worked.

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

To check I opened console in Pycharm and entered below string. You may check the output below. I don't understand this behaviour.

[image]Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Ok. I got the issue. The code works fine in python with u'ウィメン'. There is something wrong with Pycharm console.